# doPostBack + beforeclose on dialago

Tags: c#, jquery

I need to refresh the parent page once close the dialog, on other pages it is worked fine but in my page an error occurred !!!

This is the  function on button click "btnAddCvg"

```
 function showDialog() {
        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
        $("#modalIframeId").attr("src", "AddCoverage.aspx");
        return false;
    }

 $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            height: 600,
            width: 950,
            buttons: {
                'Close': function () {
                    $('#dialog').dialog('close');

                }
            },
            beforeClose: function (event, ui) {
                //                    __doPostBack("panel1");



            }
        });
    });
```

i have on the same page an update panel :

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="panel1" runat="server" OnLoad="UpdatePanel1_Load">
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and in the code behind:

```
 protected void UpdatePanel1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       grid_list_quotes.DataBind();

}
```

what should i do ???

Comment: `"an error occurred"` - Can you be more specific?

Comment: this is error from java script code !!

Comment: You're missing the point.  *What* is the error from the JavaScript code?  Or from any code?  Error messages contain *very useful* information.  Specifically about what went wrong and where it went wrong.  Please provide the *actual error*.  It should be present on the browser console.

Comment: Open Internet Explorer - Internet Options - Advance - Uncheck Disable Script Debugging (Internet Explorer) . Now open your page in internet explorer. it will give you javascript error. Please provide that error information.

Comment: GET http://localhost:24931/Web/WebResource.axd?d=sw6mPTSF6fQN4GjVzx3u1g-p50tnav…YTZ7shkkAvKzHsjhqFVFQUIPDJXnNRObh13b9jPETDwQBTMTGfUc1&t=635128557218398300 404 (Not Found)  ... that's what i get from the console